# face recognition for home security system

Tags: mysql, vb.net

the project is face and pin code recognition for home security system in vb and mysql, the problem is how store face image of users in db for recognizer part, by the way i write the code for it but i dont know whats the problem that cant save images.

this code in public class

```vb
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter
Dim dbCon As MySqlConnection
Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand
Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
```

this code for add button actually is function

```vb
    Dim FileSize As UInt32
    Dim rawData() As Byte

    Dim dbCon As New MySqlConnection("Server = 127.0.0.1; database=database; uid= root; pwd= 6404")


    dbCon.Open()
    dbCon.ChangeDatabase("psdb")


    Dim COMMAND As New MySqlCommand("SELECT actor_pic, filesize, filename FROM actors WHERE actor_name = ?autoid", dbCon )
    COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("?autoid", txtname.Text)
    dr = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
    dr.Read()

    'data is in memory 

    FileSize = dr.GetUInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("filesize"))
    rawData = New Byte(FileSize) {}

    'get the bytes and filesize 

    dr.GetBytes(dr.GetOrdinal("actor_pic"), 0, rawData, 0, FileSize)

    Dim ad As New System.IO.MemoryStream(100000)
    ' Dim bm As New Bitmap

    ad.Write(rawData, 0, FileSize)

    dr.Close()
    dbCon.Close()
    dbCon.Dispose()

    ad.Dispose()




    DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
    DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1).Cells(0).Value = imagez.ToBitmap
    DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1).Height = DataGridView1.Columns(0).Width * 0.75
    ' the 0.75 * width for the height keeps it at 4:3 aspect ratio, so it looks normal.
    DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1).Cells(1).Value = "image" & DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
```